# Determine which group(s) the current user account belongs to?

Tags: c, winapi, user-accounts, usergroups

For a small utility app I'm writing at work, I have the following code to determine if the current user account is a local or domain administrator:

```
    WCHAR wszUser[UNLEN];

    GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"username", wszUser, UNLEN);

#ifndef _DEBUG
    if (StrCmpIW(wszUser, L"Administrator") != 0)
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, L"This program can only be run as Administrator.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
        return 0;
    }
#endif
```

This works in our case right now because:

1. The domain admin account we have is the built-in Administrator account
2. We don't have any other domain admin accounts.

However, I realize that this is a bad solution because in the future we might add other domain administrator accounts.  Is there a way to determine using the Windows API whether the user account that the process is running from belongs to either the Domain Admins group, or `BUILTIN\Administrators`, or not?

This is not a security concern since the app won't actually be able to do anything useful unless it's running as an Administrator, this is just for robustness.

Comment: The correct solution in this case is to use the `/MANIFESTUAC:level=requireAdministrator` linker option, or if you already have a manifest, add a `requestedExecutionLevel` entry with `level="requireAdministrator"` [as described here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17968/making-your-application-uac-aware).

Comment: If you need to retrieve group information for some other reason, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450998/need-to-retrieve-all-groups-a-user-belongs-to-in-c . But in this case, I agree with @HarryJohnston.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution in this case is to set the `/MANIFESTUAC:level=requireAdministrator` linker option, or if you already have a manifest, add a `requestedExecutionLevel` entry [as described here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17968/making-your-application-uac-aware).

That way, Windows will refuse to run the program without elevated privileges, and you don't need to do anything in your code.  This will also make it easier on the user, because they don't have to explicitly run your code elevated in order for it to work; Windows will prompt them as necessary.

However, if you *really* want to do it programmatically, [see the documentation for the CheckTokenMembership function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389.aspx), which even has example code that does exactly what you are asking for. :-)