# From a C++ application, how can I check if a specific user in Active Directory is part of a particular security group?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently working on a C++ application that needs to authenticate a user against the Active Directory on our domain (which I have working), and then also check if that user is part of a particular security group in that Active Directory. I've been using WinLDAP to authenticate (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/establishing-an-ldap-session), and I've had no problems there. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be anything in the API for checking which security groups a user belongs to (in our Active Directory), or checking if they are a member of a specific group.

I've found some answers in other threads, but they either (1) are written in C# or (2) only tell you how to check the Active Directory groups for the *current user* on that Windows machine, which is not what I need. The current user on the PC might not be the same person logging into our application, or they might use a different account to log into their PC than they use for authenticating against the Active Directory. I need to be able to specify the user I'm checking the security groups for.

The solution doesn't need to use LDAP, but it does need to work in C++ and Windows. Our application also uses Qt, so I'm certainly open to options that require Qt. I'm really just looking for a simple way to say *"Does user [X] belong to group [Y] in the Active Directory on domain [Z]".* Alternatively, it could work as *"List all groups that user [X] belongs to in the Active Directory on domain [Z]".* Either one is perfectly fine, as long as I can specify the user name in the AD, meaning it doesn't just operate on the current Windows user account. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_adsi/) to do this. There's a C++ example of binding to a user account using [`ADsGetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsgetobject) here: [Binding With GetObject and ADsGetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/binding-with-getobject-and-adsgetobject)

If you specify `IID_IADsUser` as the `riid` parameter, you can get an [`IADsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadsuser) object, and then use [`IADsUser::Groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-groups) to get all the groups that the user is a member of.

The C# examples can still be helpful to you, since the [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices) namespace is really just a wrapper around ADSI. For example, this C#:

```cs
var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,DC=fabrikam,DC=com");
```

is equivalent to this in C++:

```
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,DC=fabrikam,DC=com", IID_IADsUser, (void**) &pUser);
```

[`DirectoryEntry.Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties) is equivalent to [`IADs::Get`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-get)/[`IADs::GetEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-getex)

[`DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache) is equivalent to [`IADs::GetInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-getinfo)/[`IADs::GetInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-getinfoex)

[`DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.commitchanges) is equivalent to [`IADs::SetInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iads-setinfo)

Comment: I'm having trouble with the "ADs Path" expected by the "ADsGetObject" function. I've tried both the [LDAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath) and [WinNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/winnt-adspath) versions, but I keep getting errors on both.  
  
For example:
`LDAP://CN=test_user,CN=users,DC=ourdomain,DC=com` --> ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN
`LDAP://dc1.ourdomain.com/CN=test_user,CN=users,DC=ourdomain,DC=com` ---> ERROR_DS_OPERATIONS_ERROR  
  
, and with WinNT:
`WinNT://ourdomain.com/test_user,user` --> ER_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: If the computer you're running this from is not joined to the same or a trusted domain, it probably doesn't know where to go to find `DC=ourdomain,DC=com`, so you have to tell it by including the DNS name of the domain in the LDAP path, which it looks like you tried by specifying the DC in `LDAP://dc1.ourdomain.com/CN=test_user,CN=users,DC=ourdomain,DC=com`. You can try using just the domain name, rather than a specific DC: `LDAP://ourdomain.com/CN=test_user,CN=users,DC=ourdomain,DC=com`

Comment: I tried that, and my PC has joined this domain. I even simplified it to just "LDAP://ourdomain.com" or "LDAP://ourdomain". I know it's valid because I'm not getting either the "no such domain" or "server down" errors. The *only* error I continue getting is ERROR_DS_OPERATIONS_ERROR. I don't think it's because I have the wrong domain. Something else seems to be wrong, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. These are the only lines I have so far:
`HRESULT hr;
IADs* pObject;
CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://ourdomain.com", IID_IADs, (void**)&pObject);`

Comment: Are you able to use Active Directory Users and Computers to browse your domain? Or ldp.exe?

Comment: I managed to get `ADsOpenObject` to work instead of `ADsGetObject`. I set the "riid" parameter to "IID_IADsUser" so I have a user object to work with, and it said it was successful. However, when I execute the next two lines with that object: `IADsMembers* groups;  pObjectUser->Groups(&groups);`  I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the list of groups. None of the functions for "IADsMembers" seem to be what I need. Is "IADsMembers" the wrong pointer type? If not, how should I be iterating over the returned groups pointer to see the groups?

Comment: The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-groups) says that `IADsUser->Groups()` returns "A pointer to a pointer to the IADsMembers interface on a members object that can be enumerated using IEnumVARIANT to determine the groups to which this end-user belongs," but it doesn't give any examples of how to iterate over the groups.

Comment: There's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482145/1202807). That example apparently used to be on the documentation page, but isn't anymore.